# Servlet FileUpload: how to read custom type object from multitype form?

Tags: java, servlets, file-upload

I use `org.apache.commons.fileupload` to read file from multitype form. The question is how to read custom type object from this form. I tried to use `fileitem.get()` which gives byte representation of this field, but during deserialization i had an exception `java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 62792E74`. 
`fileitem.getString()` gives following representation of this object:

```
by.training.sixthgroup.model.Genre@716e2626
```

Some code also can help you

```
Genre genre = (Genre) deserialize(fileItem.get());

public static Object deserialize(byte[] data) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        ByteArrayInputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(data);
        ObjectInputStream is = new ObjectInputStream(in);
        return is.readObject();
}
```